# Menu Horizontal - CSS

Tags: css, submenu

Estou tentando aprender a trabalhar com menus horizontais em CSS. Estou começando e portanto estou com um dúvida boba e não encontrei nada na internet parecido com a minha questão (Talvez eu não conheço os termos corretos para o problema).

O meu problema é que todos os meus sub-menus estão alinhando embaixo do primeiro elemento do menu principal. Coloquei aqui no [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wfidelis36/2cq8fkn2/) o HTML e o CSS que eu fiz.

Espero que alguém possa me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi corretamente o porquê (também não fiquei procurando), mas precisa flutuar os menus "pais":

```
.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;        /* <- Adicione essa propriedade */
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

#### [JSFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/2cq8fkn2/2/)

Comment: Não entendi o porque também. Pra mim não fez muito sentido, mas bom que me ajudou a resolver. Talvez alguém aqui do SO consiga entender hehehe \o